# Is there a way to tell Selenium runner where the driver is using the command line?

Tags: selenium, command-line, environment-variables, selenium-chromedriver

I have just installed Selenium Runner on my Mac (Mojave) but I will also later be running it on CentOS 7.  Is there any way I can tell my process the path of the chromedriver when I run it from a command line?  Currently, I'm running it like so ...

```
/usr/local/bin/selenium-side-runner /tmp/0ba4e59f-53d5-43ff-b7ff-127499868cf3.side
```

but getting this error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
```

After reading the insturxctions here -- https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/ , there is much talk about adding the path to the driver in the PATH environment variable.  However, I'm running my script from a separate process that' deson't have access to my PATH, so I'd like a bit more control over how to tell Selnium Runner where the driver is.

**Edit:** Using Tarun's solution I get the following strange result ...

```
localhost:selenium davea$ selenium-side-runner  -c "chromeOptions.binary='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'" myTestFile.side
info:    Running myTestFile.side
 FAIL  ./DefaultSuite.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?
```

**Edit 2:**

Contents of my ".side.yml" file and path to chromedriver ...

```
localhost:selenium davea$ cat .side.yml 
capabilities:
  browserName: 'chrome'
  chromeOptions:
    binary: '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/chromedriver_mac'
  firefoxOptions:
    binary: '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/geckodriver_mac'

localhost:selenium davea$ ls -al /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/chromedriver_mac
-rwxr-xr-x 1 davea staff 14994520 Jun 11 19:42 /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/chromedriver_mac
```

Yet I still get the same result complaining about driver can't be found ...

```
localhost:selenium davea$ selenium-side-runner myTestSpike.side 
info:    Running myTestSpike.side
 FAIL  ./DefaultSuite.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
```

Comment: Just a Suggestion : if you use web driver manager then you don't need to add path to your driver.
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see their readme they do specify how to do the same

https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-side-runner

```sh
selenium-side-runner -c "chromeOptions.binary='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'"
```

You can even create a `.side.yml` and save the options there

```
capabilities:
  browserName: 'chrome'
  chromeOptions:
    binary: '/path/to/chromedriver'
```

See my updates in the another question related to this

[How do I run my selenium-side-runner to execute my test against Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011098/how-do-i-run-my-selenium-side-runner-to-execute-my-test-against-firefox/57033497?noredirect=1#comment100611734_57033497)

Comment: Hi, I set things up exactly as you have it in your solution but get this error upon running things, "TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?".  There is a little more detail in the edit to my question.

Comment: @Dave, that was just example, not a working config. As the error says you need to specify the browser name as well

Comment: Hi @Tarun, Thanks for this clarification.  I edited my question to show the contents of my ".side.yml" file (which now includes the browser) and the fact that my chrome driver path actually exists based on what is listed in that file.  Yet I still get the error complaining about the fact Selenium doesn't know where the driver is.

Comment: Oh cool -- thx.  Please ignore my other comment from the other thread as I saw your comment here second.

Comment: your other answer (about the selenium-runner bug) turned out to also be the answer to this as well so you can have this bounty too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **ChromeOptions class**. You can create an instance of ChromeOptions, which has convenient methods for setting ChromeDriver-specific capabilities.

```
// Create ChromeOptions instance
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// Set your custom path of the chrome driver to the options
options.setBinary("/path/to/chrome/binary");

// Pass the options object to the ChromeDriver instance
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Since Selenium version 3.6.0, the ChromeOptions class in Java also implements the Capabilities interface, allowing you to specify other WebDriver capabilities not specific to ChromeDriver.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Add the WebDriver proxy capability.
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("myhttpproxy:3337");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

// Add a ChromeDriver-specific capability.
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Please go through this link for much more options** [Capabilities & ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Refer this link [Command line runner](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/).

**Chrome specific capabilities**
If you have Chrome installed in a non-standard location on your machine you can specify the path so ChromeDriver knows where to look.

```
selenium-side-runner -c "chromeOptions.binary='/path/to/non-standard/Chrome/install'"
```

With Chrome specific capabilities you can also run the tests headlessly.

```
selenium-side-runner -c "chromeOptions.args=[disable-infobars, headless]"
```

Comment: What file are you doing this in?  I recorded my test case using the Selenium IDE for chrome, which gives me a .side file.

Comment: This is written in Java file. Go though this link [Chrome Options for running WebDriver Tests](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/using-chrome-options-for-webdriver-tests) for running WebDriver Tests

Comment: Yeah but I'm not running a Java file, I'm using the selenium-side-runner utility.  That's why I'd like to know how to configure things through the command line.

Comment: @Dave Updated my answer for Selenium-side-runner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a shell you can set an env variable which will be passed into the process your run.  So just do this:

```
env "webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver" /usr/local/bin/selenium-side-runner /tmp/0ba4e59f-53d5-43ff-b7ff-127499868cf3.side
```

Comment: I am running in a bash shell, but when I run this command, "export webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver" I get the error, "-bash: export: `webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver': not a valid identifier"

Comment: It would seem I forgot that  bash and . with env variables is a PITA, answer updated, although YMMV.