# How do I run my selenium-side-runner to execute my test against Firefox?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, command-line

I just installed selenium-side-runner on Mac Mojave and am trying to run a test from the command line using a test I recorded in the IDE.  My test file name is "myTest.side".  I created a "myTest.side.yml" file to tell selenium-side-runner where my drivers are ...

```
capabilities:
  chromeOptions:
    binary: '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/chromedriver_mac'
  firefoxOptions:
    binary: '/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/geckodriver_mac'
```

However, when I try and run my tests, I'm getting this error ...

```
localhost:selenium davea$ selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox" myTest.side
info:    Running myTest.side
 FAIL  ./DefaultSuite.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    The geckodriver executable could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/ and ensure it can be found on your PATH.

      at findGeckoDriver (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js:444:11)
      at new ServiceBuilder (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js:533:22)
      at Function.createSession (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js:591:21)
      at createDriver (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:155:33)
      at Builder.build (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:670:16)
      at buildDriver (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/jest-environment-selenium/dist/index.js:66:17)
      at WebdriverEnvironment.setup (../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/jest-environment-selenium/dist/index.js:37:32)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

How do I run my test from the command line using Firefox?

Comment: The file name should `.side.yml` and not `myTest.side.yml`

Comment: Hi @Tarun, just saw this comment.  Deleting my comment from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented earlier, the reason your code doesn't work is the file naming convention.

By default the `selenium-side-runner` will pick the file `.side.yml` and not `<somename>.side.yml`

So if you just rename the file, it should pickup the correct details for you

**Update: 16th July**

After lots of hours of debugging, it seems what you are experiencing is a bug. So what happens is quite visible in the error

```
at new ServiceBuilder (selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:232:13)
at getDefaultService (selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:321:22)
at Function.createSession (selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:694:44)
at createDriver (selenium-webdriver/index.js:155:33)
at Builder.build (selenium-webdriver/index.js:662:16)
at buildDriver (jest-environment-selenium/dist/index.js:73:17)
at WebdriverEnvironment.setup (jest-environment-selenium/dist/index.js:39:32)
```

`selenium-side-runner` use `jest-environment-selenium` package and calls the `setup` method with below code

```
async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.driver = await buildDriver(this.configuration);
  }
```

Now this `configuration` is being passed using `jest` and is there in the `package.json` of the test files generated on the fly

[image: Config]

As you can see the configuration is passed. Now if we look at the `jest-environment-selenium` and the `buildDriver` function

```
async function buildDriver(configuration) {
  const driver = new _seleniumWebdriver2.default.Builder().withCapabilities(configuration.capabilities);

  if (configuration.server) driver.usingServer(configuration.server);
  if (configuration.proxyType) {
    let prxy;
    if (configuration.proxyType === 'socks') {
      prxy = _proxy2.default.socks(configuration.proxyOptions.socksProxy, configuration.proxyOptions.socksVersion);
    } else {
      prxy = _proxy2.default[configuration.proxyType](configuration.proxyOptions);
    }
    driver.setProxy(prxy);
  }

  return driver.build();
}
```

The driver does get initiated with `withCapabilities(configuration.capabilities)` and the capabilites do have the driver path also, but it seems `webdriver` will do nothing of these options. The initiator needs do all the work

If I update the function like below

```
async function buildDriver(configuration) {
  const driver = new _seleniumWebdriver2.default.Builder().withCapabilities(configuration.capabilities);

  if (configuration.server) driver.usingServer(configuration.server);
  if (configuration.proxyType) {
    let prxy;
    if (configuration.proxyType === 'socks') {
      prxy = _proxy2.default.socks(configuration.proxyOptions.socksProxy, configuration.proxyOptions.socksVersion);
    } else {
      prxy = _proxy2.default[configuration.proxyType](configuration.proxyOptions);
    }
    driver.setProxy(prxy);
  }

  if (configuration.capabilities && configuration.capabilities.chromeOptions) {
    var options = new _chrome.Options()
    var service = new _chrome.ServiceBuilder(configuration.capabilities.chromeOptions.binary || null)
    driver.setChromeService(service)
  }
  return driver.build();
}
```

And now the test starts working. The repo for `jest-environment-selenium` is available on below

https://github.com/applitools/jest-environment-selenium

You can report and discuss the issue. In the meantime can workaround the issue by running the command like below

```sh
$ PATH=/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/:$PATH selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox" myTest.side
```

Comment: You want the config file as `.side.yml`, no file name

Comment: I think the contents of my ".side.yml" file are themselves flawed.  I keep getting a "The geckodriver executable could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/ and ensure it can be found on your PATH." error.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal git repo? I will see if I can reproduce the issue on my machine

Comment: If you're able to get it running with any .side.yml file, please post that config in your answer and then the link to the driver (maybe I downloaded the wrong one?).  I feel there is something very simple that I'm messing up but I can't figure out what that would be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a <kbd>.side.yml</kbd> file in the directory you'll be running your tests from. The runner will pick it up automatically. Here is an example of the file's contents. As is from [Selenium Command-Line Runner](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/).

So please make sure to change the name of the file.

Or you can use <kbd>--config-file</kbd> without changing the name of your file. `--config-file` will ignore the `.side.yml` and picks up the configuration from the specified path.

```
selenium-side-runner --config-file "/path/to/your/config.yaml"
```

Credit Goes of [Selenium IDE Documenation](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/)

Comment: I ran the command 'selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox" --config-file "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/myTeste.side.yml" myTeste.side' with te config listed in my question but still got the error, "The geckodriver executable could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/ and ensure it can be found on your PATH.".